# Subject Verb Agreement in a Nominative Clause

Tags: verb-agreement, subordinate-clauses

Okay, so I have two examples of a possible sentence:

1 - "The country's strategic value requires that it maintain a standing army."

2 - "The country's strategic value requires that it maintains a standing army."

Normally I'd go looking for examples but I'm finding both:

"If a building is being used as a hospital, the interpretation requires that it maintain two or more patients at the same time."

"Adaptation of a protein to nonambient conditions requires that it maintains its catalytic activity as well as its structure."

The first one sounds correct to me but of course it can't actually be correct. "It maintain"? I'm really scratching my head here.

Comment: *... that it maintain* is the present subjunctive mood, which is still used relatively often in the U.S., but is quite a bit rarer in the U.K. What dialect of English do you want to write in, and how formal do you want to be? (And note *... requires it to maintain* is another possibility.)

Comment: It's not a "nominative clause". Nominative is a case, and English doesn't have cases. The term is _noun clause_, i.e, a clause being used as a noun. In this case, the clauses are all direct objects of the verb _require_, which can take an uninflected _that_ clause (_maintain_) or an inflected one (_maintains_). This is about _require_ having different usages; nothing special, really.

Comment: Interestingly, [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=require_INF+that+it+maintain%2Crequire_INF+that+it+maintains&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t3%3B%2Crequire_INF%20that%20it%20maintain%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brequires%20that%20it%20maintain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brequired%20that%20it%20maintain%3B%2Cc0) finds **no examples** of "requires that it maintains". The prevailing mood appears to be subjunctive on *both* sides of the pond.

Comment: Sorry to point this out and "The country's strategic value" can't match your Question; not at face value, anyway.

Singular *strategic value* describes what that country is worth to others, usually in military terms.

Plural *strategic values* describes that country's principles, in purely philosophical or political terms.

Comment: It was a quick example, but the worth of the country to its neighbors would also require that it keep a standing army to defend itself from those neighbors. I think that the use of "strategic values" as a matter of philosophy regarding strategy would be quite strange in any context. In any case, I've gotten what I needed from this question, so I don't know that this distinction is particularly important.